# Laravel 5 - Creating Artisan Command for Packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have been following along http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands and able to create artisan command in Laravel 5. But, how can I create artisan command and package it to packages?

Comment: Create a new project and take a look at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/*, there is a "Console" folder where you can see how the make:auth command works, and the Auth folder itself is a package, so, you can follow that as an example :)!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can and should register the package commands inside a service provider using `$this->commands()` in the `register()` method:

```
namespace Vendor\Package;

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $commands = [
        'Vendor\Package\Commands\MyCommand',
        'Vendor\Package\Commands\FooCommand',
        'Vendor\Package\Commands\BarCommand',
    ];

    public function register(){
        $this->commands($this->commands);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I refer it to my command file? For e.g, if I put all command files in `Commands` folder, where the commands folder is on the same path of MyServiceProvider. How can I link to it?

Comment: First, the commands have to be autoloaded. Normally, if the other files in your package work that should be the case. (Make sure the commands are in the right namespace corresponding to it's directory. This should be something like `namespace Vendor\Package\Commands`) Then you only have to reference it with it's fully qualified name in the `$commands` array. Like in my edited answer...

Comment: If the $defferred=true is set then the commands do not appear on artisan output.. :(

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 5.6 it's very easy.

class FooCommand,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class FooCommand extends Command {

    protected $signature = 'foo:method';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle() {
        echo 'foo';
    }

}
```

this is the **serviceprovider** of package. (Just need to add $this->commands() part to boot function).

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Package;

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
        $this->commands([
            \Vendor\Package\Commands\FooCommand ::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now we can call the command like this

> php artisan foo:method

This will echo 'foo' from command handle method. The important part is giving correct namespace of command file inside boot function of package service provider.